# Can Android handle .pack files?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

For example in LibGDX you have a TextureAtlas and you can use `findRegion()` method. With .pack you can search in the Texture and get the position, width and height from the sprite.

Have Android also a method what can handle .pack files?
If not:
Can you convert LibGDX Texture to an android bitmap?